# How to specify Integrator via persistence.xml?

Tags: hibernate

I've created an `InitializeCollectionEventListener` and have successfully installed it programmatically with an Integrator using `BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyIntegrator()`.

While browsing the Hibernate code, I noticed that there is a `hibernate.integrator_provider` property in `EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.INTEGRATOR_PROVIDER`.

I have tried specifying it in persistence.xml using

```
<property name="hibernate.integrator_provider" value="com.mystuff.MyIntegratorProvider" />
```

but that seemed to have no effect.

When debugging `EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl` I see that my property is present in that `PersistenceUnitDescriptor`, but the code only looks for the `INTEGRATOR_PROVIDER` in some Map called `integrationSettings`.

Is there a declarative way to get my `IntegratorProvider` into this Map?

Comment: Which Java EE container are you using?

Comment: I think, it has been fixed in 5.4.9: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13614